# OpenPGP Applet not working after 17.10

Tags: gnome, upgrade, 17.10

So I upgraded my Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 to 17.10 which I guess is now more akin to the normal Ubuntu 17.10 setup however now OpenPGP Applet is not working.

Is this to do with the now removal of the legacy drawer in Gnome which this applet used for interaction?

Comment: You could check that if you test it with the "Topicons plus" extension which you can find on extensions.gnome.org. I got many programs running with this.

Comment: @Videonauth This isn't working :( It only shows ClipIt which I use for managing my clipboard. No OpenPGP Applet, Dropbox, etc

Comment: This is why I posted it as a comment and not as an answer, sad it didn't work out. Never worked myself with the openPGP applet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using `openpgp-applet` for a while because I really like the simplicity of it, but the fact that it's busted in newer versions of Ubuntu (or, more specifically, Gnome) has been a real bummer.

In order to preserve most of the functionality, I went ahead and made a fork of the app that will launch the `applet` in a window instead of as a status icon. You can find it on this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/mmarsalko/openpgp-applet-window).